# useCallback not giving the required effect i need in my program

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, material-ui, frontend

In the following code; as per my knowledege about **useCallback hook** *'rerendering has happened!'* message should be displayed only when i am typing something inside the input field and shouldn't be printed when I am clicking on the **Toggle button**. But the message does print for the 2nd case. Why?

**my App.js file**

```
import {useState, useCallback} from 'react'
import List from './List'

function App() {
  const [a, seta] = useState('')
  const [Color, setColor] = useState("#12ab34")

  const message = useCallback(() => {
    console.log('rerendering has happened!')
    return [a+'SAMSUNG', a+'MOTO', a+'NOKIA']
  }, [a])

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input value={a} onChange={e => seta(e.target.value)} />
      <button onClick={() => Color === "#12ab34" ? setColor("#abb111") : setColor("#12ab34") }>toggle</button>
      <List message={message()} Color={Color}/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**my List.js file**

```
import React from 'react'

export default function List({message, Color}){
    return (<>
    <ul>
    <li style={{color: Color}}>{message[0]}</li>
    <li style={{color: Color}}>{message[1]}</li>
    <li style={{color: Color}}>{message[2]}</li>
    </ul>
</>)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function is not created multiple times don't worry. The log statement

```
'rerendering has happened!'
```

is running multiple times. It is because your function `message()` runs multiple times.

Look at `<List message={message()} Color={Color}/>`.
What you want to do is memoize the value returned from your function, and do not call it unnecessarily.

```
import { useState, useCallback, useMemo } from "react";
import List from "./List";

function App() {
  const [a, seta] = useState("");
  const [Color, setColor] = useState("#12ab34");
  console.log({ a });
  const message = useCallback(() => {
    console.log("rerendering has happened!");
    return [a + "SAMSUNG", a + "MOTO", a + "NOKIA"];
  }, [a]);

  const val = useMemo(() => message(), [message]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input value={a} onChange={(e) => seta(e.target.value)} />
      <button
        onClick={() =>
          Color === "#12ab34" ? setColor("#abb111") : setColor("#12ab34")
        }
      >
        toggle
      </button>
      <List message={val} Color={Color} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

[Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-allen-ejbcih?file=/src/App.js:0-751)

That being said, the above approach is still counter intuitive to me. The purpose of your function is to calculate a value,. And in your `<List...` statement, you simple call the function to get the value. So basically you do not need the function anywhere, and just the value. Using `useMemo` will do the job here.

```
import { useState, useCallback, useMemo } from "react";
import List from "./List";

function App() {
  const [a, seta] = useState("");
  const [Color, setColor] = useState("#12ab34");
  console.log({ a });
  const message = useMemo(() => {
    console.log("rerendering has happened!");
    return [a + "SAMSUNG", a + "MOTO", a + "NOKIA"];
  }, [a]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input value={a} onChange={(e) => seta(e.target.value)} />
      <button
        onClick={() =>
          Color === "#12ab34" ? setColor("#abb111") : setColor("#12ab34")
        }
      >
        toggle
      </button>
      <List message={message} Color={Color} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

[Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-dream-7r26fz?file=/src/App.js:0-699)

Answer (score 1):

When you use `UseCallback` the function will be called on each render the difference is a memorized version of it will be called (new instance will NOT be created).
It is useful when you're passing functions as props.

In your case, you should consider using `UseMemo` instead which returns a memorized value.